# Best way to flatten a 2D matrix to 1D when sliced from a 3D matrix variable

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, reshape

I have a 3D matrix in Matlab to store a sequence of 2D arrays. I'm having to find the maximal value and its row and column indices, which is pretty straightforward for a single variable that holds a 2D array as in

```
A = rand(10,10);
[m,i] = max(A(:));
[I,J] = ind2sub( size(A) , i )
```

The trouble is that I cannot use this syntax for the 3D matrix

```
A = rand(10,10,3);
[m,i] = max( A(:,:,1)(:) );
[I,J] = ind2sub(size( A(:,:,1) ), i )

Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

I could create a temporary variable to store the 2D slice, but I'd thought I'd see if there's a better means of doing this, maybe making a call to reshape? Is there any way to use the simple linearizing/flattening operator `(:)` in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
[B i]=max(reshape(A,[],size(A,3)));
[II,JJ]=ind2sub(size(A),i );
```

The only limitation is that it wont treat well cases where there is more than one max per 2D slice.

Comment: Sweet use of both reshape and ind2sub! The way ind2sub is used here seems a little "off-label" (but not wrong). A more readable version may be [II,JJ]=ind2sub([size(A,1) size(A,2)],i);

Comment: dang it all, looks like I can't use that flattening operator. It's good that reshape is available.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to a cell array and use [`cellfun`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html?searchHighlight=cellfun)

```
B=mat2cell(reshape(A,[1, size(A,2).^2, size(A,3)]),[1],[size(A,2).^2], [ones(size(A,3),1)]);
[M,I]= cellfun(@max,B)
[R,C] = ind2sub(size(A),I);
```

`M` contains the maximum value and `I` the corresponding index.

---

Assuming that `A` is a `3x3x2` array.

```
A =[

    0.7952    0.4456    0.7547
    0.1869    0.6463    0.2760
    0.4898    0.7094    0.6797];

A(:,:,2) =[

    0.6551    0.4984    0.5853
    0.1626    0.9597    0.2238
    0.1190    0.3404    0.7513];
```

Convert each slice into a `1x9x2` cell array

```
B=mat2cell(reshape(A,[1, size(A,2).^2, size(A,3)]),[1],[size(A,2).^2], [ones(size(A,3),1)]);

B(:,:,1) = 

    [1x9 double]


B(:,:,2) = 

    [1x9 double]
```

Take the maximum of each slice. `R` is the row and `C` is the column for the respective maximum value in `M`.

```
[M,I]= cellfun(@max,B)
[R,C] = ind2sub(size(A),I)

R(:,:,1) =

     1

R(:,:,2) =

     2

C(:,:,1) =

     1

C(:,:,2) =

     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Successively taking max will directly pull out the indices in (reverse) order:

```
A = rand(10,10,3);
[m,J] = max(max(A(:,:,1)));
[m,I] = max(A(:,J,1));
```

%check:
A(I,J,1) == m